# Функция поиска наибольшего из n чисел

Tags: python

При помощи функции ищу наибольшее число из трех a,b,c:

```
def biggest(a,b,c):
    if a > b:
        if a > c:
            return a
        else:
            return c
    else:
        if b > c:
             return b
        else:
             return c

print biggest(5,6,8)
```

Что, если мне нужно искать из 4х и более чисел? (a,b,c,x,x,x,x.. )

Придерживаясь базовой схемы.

Comment: Вам принципиально своё написать или может хватит встроенной в питон функции `max(a, b, c, x, x, x, x...)`?

Comment: Если вам не только наибольшее значение нужно, но и сравнить (отсортировать) все заданные числа, то могут существовать эффективные реализации для фиксированных маленьких `n`: [Fastest sort of fixed length 6 int array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2786899/4279)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 11):

```
max(2, 1, 15, -12, 6)
```

Если без использования [max](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#max):

```
def biggest(mx, *args):
    for a in args:
        if mx < a: mx = a
    return mx
```

или

```
import heapq
def biggest(*args):
    return heapq.nlargest(1, args)[0]
```

или

```
list(sorted((2, 1, 15, -12, 6)))[-1]
```

out:

```
print(biggest(2, 1, 15, -12, 6))
```

Comment: Красавчик, что сказать то.

Comment: Зачем вы передаете первый аргумент mx?

Comment: @Trymount чтобы избежать лишней строки mx = args[0] и излишней проверки первого аргумента или среза в for a in args:. Например как в ответе privod

Comment: @vadimvaduxa ясно, спасибо!

Comment: `minmax()` функцию, возвращающую min и max одновременно, можно как `O(n)` операцию реализовать, а `sorted()` это `O(n*log n)` операция (если функцию не определять, то для известного ввода с маленькими n, можно конечно и sorted() вызов оставить.

Answer (score 1):

Функция с переменным количеством аргументов:

```
def biggest(* args):
    max = args[0]
    for item in args[1:]:
        if item > max:
            max = item
    return max

print(biggest(5,27,8,7,2,19))
```

**args** - это кортеж из всех переданных аргументов функции, и с переменной можно работать также, как и с кортежем.
Подробнее [здесь](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/vse-o-funkciyax-i-ix-argumentax.html).

Comment: числа бывают отрицательными